# transpose/rotate a block of a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

i have a 6x6 matrix as a list of lists in python. The matrix is divided into 4 square blocks of size 3x3. I want a way to take a transpose of only 1 block. I can do it using the traditional method of going through each element and copying it into another array and back and so on but I want to see if there is a better way, (transposing a matrix in python can be done in one line using the zip method)

for eg this is the representation of the matrix and its blocks

```
 block 1  block 2
+-------+-------+
| . . . | . . . |
| . . 2 | 1 . . |
| . . . | . . . |
+-------+-------+
| . . . | . . . |
| . . . | . . . |
| . 1 . | . . . |
+-------+-------+
 block 3  block 4
```

and rotate(3, right) should result in this

```
 block 1  block 2
+-------+-------+
| . . . | . . . |
| . . 2 | 1 . . |
| . . . | . . . |
+-------+-------+
| . . . | . . . |
| 1 . . | . . . |
| . . . | . . . |
+-------+-------+
 block 3  block 4
```

I want to find a method that takes in a block number and rotates only that block left or right. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Should the operation be in place?

Comment: yes, It needs to be in place, or at least, the result needs to be written back to the original matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Sven Marnach's idea to use `np.rot90`, here is a version which rotates the quadrant clockwise (as requested?). In the key step

```
block3[:] = np.rot90(block3.copy(),-1)
```

a `copy()` is used on the right-hand side (RHS). Without the `copy()`, as values are assigned to `block3`, the underlying data used on the RHS is also changed. This muddles the values used in subsquent assignments. Without the `copy()`, multiple same values are spread about `block3`.

I don't see a way to do this operation without a copy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6)
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [18 19 20 21 22 23]
#  [24 25 26 27 28 29]
#  [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
block3 = a[3:6, 0:3]

# To rotate counterclockwise
block3[:] = np.rot90(block3.copy())
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [20 26 32 21 22 23]
#  [19 25 31 27 28 29]
#  [18 24 30 33 34 35]]

# To rotate clockwise
a = np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6)
block3 = a[3:6, 0:3]
block3[:] = np.rot90(block3.copy(),-1)
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [30 24 18 21 22 23]
#  [31 25 19 27 28 29]
#  [32 26 20 33 34 35]]
```

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, here's how simple this in in NumPy:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(36).reshape(6, 6)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
>>> block3 = a[3:6, 0:3]
>>> block3[:] = numpy.rot90(block3, 1).copy()
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [20, 26, 32, 21, 22, 23],
       [26, 25, 31, 27, 28, 29],
       [20, 26, 20, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Comment: +1 for numpy.rot90. Note however that copying the right-hand side to `block3[:]` in-place has an undesireable side-effect -- as new values are assigned to `block3`, the underlying values on the right-hand side get overwritten too, leaving multiple copies of the same value in the result.

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks for pointing this out.  I didn't even look at the result -- I was sure `numpy.rot90()` is returning a new array, not a view.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a solution to define a matrix as a dictionary of blocks and a block as a list of lists?
In your example (replace transpose() with the function you use to transpose it):

```
Matrix={1:block1,2:block2,3:block3,4:block4}
block3=transpose(block3)
Matrix[3]=block3
```

Comment: not really since I need to perform other matrix operations which this structure will not allow or will over complicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to rotate a "Block" from the matrix you have provided:

```
matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

def rotate(m, right):
    rm = []
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        if right:
            rm.append([row[i] for row in reversed(m)])
        else:
            rm.append([row[i] for row in m])
    return rm
```

`right` is a `Bool`
This will return a `list of lists`

you can also use:

```
def rotate(m, right):
    if right:
        return list(zip(*reversed(m)))
    else:
        return list(zip(*m))
```

but this will return a `list of tuples`

---

EDIT:

If we are talking about a matrix of type:

```
matrix = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], # block 1
          [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], # block 2
          [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], # block 3
          [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  # block 4
         ]
```

you would access block 3 by using `matrix[2]`

so the rotate function would be used like:
`rotate(matrix[2], True) #rotate block 3, right`

Comment: A list of list of numbers it the matrix I provided in the example, if its a list of list of list of numbers, you can select the 3rd block by simply going `rotate(matrix[2], True/False)`

Comment: but how do you extract only the block to pass it into the function?

Comment: one "block" of a `list of lists of lists of numbers` is a `list of lists of numbers` which would equate to `matrix[x]` so to pass the first block you would use `matrix[0]`, to pass the second `matrix[1]` etc, etc.

Comment: its only a list of list of numbers, not 3 nested lists.

Comment: I dont see how there can be blocks if you only have a list of list of numbers (which I define as a single matrix). Define `block` in your question please. Unless you have all of one 'block' in one list, instead of a rows... in which case you will need to use `list slicing` to get access to your blocks.

Comment: blocks refers to a part of the matrix, not a single element of a matrix. list slicing would probably be required in this case.

Comment: Ah i see what you want to do now, I assumed you stored your matrix differently to how you have, you should use `Sven Marnach's` solution, It will be far superior to anything I can come up with for this type of problem, specially since it uses `NumPy`